Why aren't the air vents getting rid of air in the underfloor heating system?
I am looking for some expert advice on underfloor heating.
I tried to turn on the heating for the first time: the temperature does not rise, and the pipes make a continuous noise as if there was air in the system. The pistons in the four flow gauges move up and down. I don’t have experience with underfloor heating systems, but I assume the system needs bleeding.

The system seems to be fitted with two automatic air vents (brass - in the picture): shouldn’t these get rid of the air automatically?;
How should I go about bleeding the system, if that is what needs to be done regardless of the air vent?

I have attached a picture of the manifold.
Thank you very much in advance.


The brass pots on the right are indeed the vents, you need to loosen the nub on top before it will start venting.
They are left closed in case they start leaking.
